# How to get radio button value from gentlest() method with jinja2 syntax inside?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm having a problem with request.form.getlist(), part of my HTML looks like:

```
 {{ question.optionA }} <input type="radio" value="{{ question.optionA }}" name="myradio_{{question.id}}">
 {{ question.optionB }} <input type="radio" value="{{ question.optionB }}" name="myradio_{{question.id}}">
 {{ question.optionC }} <input type="radio" value="{{ question.optionC }}" name="myradio_{{question.id}}">
 {{ question.optionD }} <input type="radio" value="{{ question.optionD }}" name="myradio_{{question.id}}">
```

now I use:

```
request.form.getlist('myradio_{{question.id}}')
```

to get radio button value, but it failed, and I think that's because I can't use {{}} inside of the getlist(). So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 question_id = "myradio_" + question.id
 radio_value = request.form[question_id]
```

Of course, you need to know your `question.id` before it.